# Get More Like This results for entire index

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I have a bunch of items(approx 100k) indexed by solr and I am able to successfully query solr to retrieve more like this items for a specific item.  What I'd like to be able to do is efficiently export the more like this items for every item in the index.  At the moment I'm just looping through every item and saving the results.  This seems inefficient to me, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't think there is a direct way for this. You would need to check some other framework which groups/clusters the documents and you would know the groups and the similar documents in it.

Comment: Sounds like a recommender to me. Why exactly is it inefficient, do you need more functionality than _"what are the other entities similar to X?"_? Solr can return MLT results for **all** documents at once if you use the `q=*` :-)

Comment: @aitchnyu, it'd be nice to just make one query to the server instead of 100k.  The q=* works well, just needed to change &rows= as well or i'm limited to 10. If you add your answer I can give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Just be careful not to overload Solr with an extreme request :-)